# When to use "commitment" or "obligation"?

Tags: meaning

I am asking for the British English use of "commitment" and "obligation".

Referring to the **Cambridge** definitions:

- Under no "[obligation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/obligation)" to pay something...
- Players must make a "[commitment](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/commitment)" to play for a full season.

In both definitions, it seems to me that there is a liability. I am asking for its use in business contracts, sales & projects etc.

Comment: I think a commitment is an obligation that is voluntarily undertaken. Does a dictionary say something different?

Comment: Yes, you commit yourself to do something, but circumstances oblige you to do it.

Comment: I often read "commitment" which expresses  engagement. So currently, I would define "obligation" as a stronger and more binding expression, especially in terms of contracts.

Comment: Here is an example from the book "Advanced Commercial Correspondence" :  "This would greatly assist us in meeting our other commitments without straining our cash situation even further". Now, would "obligation" be interchangeable here ?

Comment: Can we use "to meet our other financial obligations" ? In my eyes, it would be clearer. Would you confirm ?